# what is multiple recursive in java

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to understand what  'multiple recursive in java' is I know that it's an activation of a method can cause more than one recursive activation of the same method. But I can't still quite understand. Please show me some code examples in java (if possible) that is easy to digest

Thank you so much.

Comment: See the example here: https://www.inf.unibz.it/~calvanese/teaching/04-05-ip/lecture-notes/uni10/node23.html If a single method call can invoke multiple recursive calls, then it is multiple recursive.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int fibonacci(int n) {
        if (n < 0) return -1;
        if (n == 0)
            return 0;
        else if (n == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
    }
```

This `fibonacci` method is very good example for multiple recursive calls.

Comment: Got it! Thank you